# Данные записываються только в один файл, а не в два

Tags: pascal

Данные берутся с файла. Четные числа нужно записать в файл g, а не четные в файл h. Все числа записываются только в файл g. Вот код:

```
var f,h,g:file of integer;
    a:array[1..10000] of integer;
    n,i:integer;
begin
Assign(f,'D:/file1.pas');
Assign(h,'D:/neparni.pas');
Assign(g,'D:/parni.pas');
Reset(f);
n:=0;
while not eof(f) do begin
Inc(n);
read(f,A[n]);
end;
close(f);
rewrite(h);
for i:=1 to n do begin
if A[i] mod 2 <> 0 then write(h,A[i]);
end;
close(h);
rewrite(g);
for i:=1 to n do begin
if A[i] mod 2 = 0 then write(g,A[i]);
end;
close(g);
end.
```

Comment: вы уверены, что во входном файле такие числа имеются? зы: вообще решение весьма усложнено. Вам надо просто читать одно число с входного файл, сразу проверять и записывать в нужных выходной файл. Не нужны эти массивы и прочие циклы.

Comment: @teran Так тоже пробовал - результат тот же.

Comment: Цикл по i надо начинать с нуля, так как массив a[n] тоже индексируется с нуля. Кроме того, не имеет смысла дважды лепить по-существу один и тот  же цикл по перебору элементов массива. Цикл сделайте один, а условий с проверкой и записей в файл - две внутри одного цикла. И проверьте изначальный файл, как вам уже советовали. Возможно в нём просто нет нечётных цифр.

Comment: @Quazimorda в файле есть и четные и нечетные цифры. Два цикла это уже крайняя мера пробовал все варианты. И масив индексируется с единицы так как это паскаль.

Comment: Пропустил объявление массива  a:array[1..10000], вот поэтому с 1 ну и n:=0 сначала наращиваете до 1, а потом уж пишете. Проглядел )). Запустите программу в пошаговом режиме (F8)  и отследите, чему на каждом шаге равен элемент массива a[i]

Comment: @Quazimorda проблема в том что там мусорные елементы не имающие никакого отношения к исходному файлу.

Comment: В таком случае необходимо объявлять массив не до 10000 элементов, а до длины исходного файла. Тогда вы и объявите и переберёте в цикле только реальные данные из исходного файла.